# pagination with neo4jphp/RESTAPI without using cypher

Tags: rest, pagination, neo4j, neo4jphp

Can anybody please help me understand how i can achieve pagination using neo4j php or REST API, but i dont want to use cypher. I am looking for pagination for both neo4j Traversal and neo4j Fulltext Index results.

For Traversal results
I was trying to find a way to use offset and limiting results but i dont see anywhere else except cypher.

I see there is Pager object that can be created in neojphp, but the only option it allows is to adjust page size and lease time, no way where i can land on a particular page offset or an offset unless i iterate through all the previous n-1 pages to get the nth page using getNextResults() function. This seems to be inefficient way.

I can also see there is a PagingIterator class or lazy iterator in java api that has page function that allows to set the current page of the iteration, which seems to solve the issue but i cant understand how i can use this using neo4jphp or REST api.

For neo4j Fulltext index(lucene)
i still cant see how i should use pagination with FT indexes. I think it should be possible in lucene. but i am not sure how i can do that with neo4jphp or REST API. Overall i think PagingIterator class may help here also but not sure how. Need some help or guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you not want to use Cypher? It's the way most things in Neo4j are heading.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to specify a page through the REST API; you can only go forward through a paged traversal. Or at least, there is no way to specify a page according to their docs, which are usually pretty thorough: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-traverse.html#rest-api-creating-a-paged-traverser

This is also true for indexes.

If you think there should be a way to page backwards through traversals and indexes, you should file a feature request on their github issues page.

Comment: Probably easier to do it with cypher's `skip n limit m`

Comment: I agree, Michael. I would like to know why DevD thinks Cypher is an unacceptable solution.

Comment: Thanks Josh and Michael, but it seems cypher would be slower than traversals although i also hear that cypher is getting better. Also again if i use getNextResults() of the neo4jphp 'pager' object i would get the desired nth page through initial n-1 iterations..and that is what offset does right scan through initial #limit*(n-1)page items to offset and extract #limit items. The pager i believe will lazy load but will have the full results in the backend but the cypher limit-offset will stop as soon it retrieves the limited results. Please correct my understanding if required......

Comment: Contd...... So I am interested in finding out which do you think would be faster out of the above two cases. Also in another-separate function i am using FT indexes (which also would slow things up i believe but which i cant do away with). Here also i wanted some pagination for the FT query results. I see it is possible to paginate the FT results with cypher but i dont see anything similar to the neo4jphp 'pager' object. Is this not possible through REST API.

Comment: @JoshAdell Sorry i forgot to tag you...and doing that now since i did not receive a response :)